# Add word at the end of lines in file by groovy

Tags: groovy

I have a `text` file (call it is **test.txt**), which content like below:

```
line_1                                                         
line_2                                                    
line_3                                                    
line_n
```

Can I add `.xml` at the end of each line of that file by **groovy**? I'm newbie in groovy. Thanks all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be done in the following way (for not too big files):

```
def f = File.createTempFile('aaa','bbb')
f.deleteOnExit()

f.text = 'line1\nline2\nline3'
def lineBreak = System.getProperty('line.separator')    
f.text = f.readLines().collect { "${it}.xml" }.join(lineBreak)

assert f.text == 'line1.xml\nline2.xml\nline3.xml'
```

For bigger files it would be better to not do it in memory but with a temporary file and the moving it.

Comment: Thank you, but actually I have a text file which has many lines. And I want to append .xml to each line, then output to another text file.

Comment: @user3530769, it should be easy. Try yourself. You need to create two file objects, then use `eachLine` closure on the first file and append method on the second file. That's not really difficult.

Answer (score 0):

**Nobody will do your homework.**
But I can make a tutorial:

1. Read the `file_input` line by line
2. Write the content of `file_input` in `file_output`
3. Append .xml to `file_output` when each line is finished

You deserve a -1 for this question, but I won't blame you because you seem new on SO. Watch out next time ;)

Comment: You wrote "you are new on SO". You don't know this. Some people have a habit of asking lots of these _homework_-style questions using various anonymous user logins to get the question count up for certain tags.

Comment: @GavinGrover and you don't know, if he is one those users